# ZXing Camera Setting Focus and Light Settings via IntentIntegrator

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, zxing

I would like to tell ZXing to load the camera with the torch light on and auto focus off (preferably set to macro).  Is there any way to do this?  I have tried setting the SharedPreferences for "preferences_front_light" to true, but com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraConfigurationManager does not seem to be able to read it as I am not sure what the name of the SharedPrefrences group is and my application context is different than the loaded intent.

I do realize that the users settings are loaded for this, but I would prefer to override those for the application that I am writing.

Any guidance would be helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do this. The idea is that the user, not the caller, is in the best position to decide whether to turn the light on. Same with focus. You can't change an app's prefs which are marked as private.

Comment: Thank you Sean!  I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @Sean - Its been a while since this post, is there a way today to set the use of the front light in the Barcode Scanner to "Automatic"? That way the app can determine if its required or not.